# Disown / background a command passed into bash

Tags: bash, background

I am trying to make a simple lock screen for my laptop running Arch / BSPWM. I found a program called cmatrix which has a screensaver flag that causes it to exit when a key is pressed. I am trying to chain together bspc commands with cmatrix and vlock to make a line that can be run to start cmatrix fullscreen, run vlock when keys are pressed, then exit after vlock exits.

My only problem with this is that in order for the lock screen to be effective, I need to quit sxhkd to prevent people from simply closing the window containing cmatrix/vlock. I have added pkill sxhkd to the chain of commands and that works. The broken part is starting sxhkd back up again. Simply tacking sxhkd on to the end doesn't work as the terminal window won't close until sxhkd finishes, which is never. In addition, if the terminal window is closed, sxhkd stops because it was running in it.

I tried using "sxhkd &", but for some reason this causes the whole thing not to run.

Here is the almost working command I have so far:

`urxvtc -e bash -c "sleep 0.1; pkill sxhkd; sleep 0.1; bspc window -t fullscreen=on; sleep 0.1; cmatrix -u 9 -s; sleep 0.1; vlock; sleep 0.1; sxhkd"`

The sleep commands are so that the programs don't come up in the wrong order (sometimes the vlock password prompt comes up before cmatrix gets to run)

What it currently does is start a new urxvt window (important if I want my terminal font for cmatrix) and it kills sxhkd to prevent anyone from closing the window. It fullscreens it using bspc and runs cmatrix. When a key is pressed, cmatrix exits and the vlock password prompts comes up. When the password is entered correctly, it tries to restart sxhkd, but they remain coupled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.  You might be able to get an answer on SuperUser (http://superuser.com).

Comment: My bad. This is mainly a bash question and there seems to be a lot of bash questions here. I'll post it there instead.

Comment: Not necessarily your bad - there ARE a lot of bash questions here.  The ones that *belong* here, however, tend to be about actual shell scripting.  If you can't find help for a particular non-programming-related *nix question on SuperUser, try ServerFault - lots of sysadmins there.

Comment: Crossposting: http://superuser.com/questions/863426/disown-background-a-command-passed-into-bash